# Combine multiple records in SQL with logical OR over every boolean

Tags: mysql

I have the following table, which describes permissions a specific user has on specific objects:

```
+------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| type | object_id | can_read | can_write | can_delete | can_create |
+------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|    0 |         1 |        1 |         0 |          0 |          1 |
|    0 |         1 |        1 |         1 |          0 |          0 |
|    0 |         2 |        1 |         0 |          0 |          0 |
|    1 |         1 |        1 |         1 |          1 |          0 |
+------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

type and object_id is integers.

type is the object type. There exist different types of objects sharing the same object_id, but should be treated as different objects due to different "type".

can_read, can_write, can_delete, can_create is booleans, which describe what the current selected user can do on the (type, object_id) tuple.

This table is the output of a couple of UNION's, which both fetches rights that an individual user has on object_id, and rights that an specific "Group" as on object_id, where the individual user is member, which is then repeated for every object type.

Now to the problem. I now want to return rows that are distinct over type and object_id. For any duplicate records, the boolean values should be an logical "OR" over every row.

In this case, the above example table should be returned as:

```
+------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| type | object_id | can_read | can_write | can_delete | can_create |
+------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|    0 |         1 |        1 |         1 |          0 |          1 |
|    0 |         2 |        1 |         0 |          0 |          0 |
|    1 |         1 |        1 |         1 |          1 |          0 |
+------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

In this case, since the selected user, has rights can_read=true, can_write=false, can_delete=false, can_create=true coming from a individual user right, on type=0,object_id=1.
And then the same user has rights can_read=true, can_write=true, can_delete=false, can_create=false coming from a Group membership on type=0,object_id=1.

The effective rights is thus can_read=true, can_write=true, can_delete=false, can_create=true.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a single value for all permissions (0 = none, 1=r, 2=w, 3=rw, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you need an aggreagtion function for merge the values in this case max valeue for each type object_id

```
   select type, object_id
      , max(can_read) can_read
      , max(can_write) can_write
      , max(can_delete) can_delete
      , max(can_create) can_create
   from my_table 
   group by type, object_id
```

and for an union

```
   select type, object_id
      , max(can_read) can_read
      , max(can_write) can_write
      , max(can_delete) can_delete
      , max(can_create) can_create
   from (

    select type, object_id, can_read, can_write, can_delete, can_create
    from table1
    union 

    select type, object_id, can_read, can_write, can_delete, can_create
    from table2
   ) t
   group by type, object_id
```

Comment: How I do this over a union? Eg, the first row and second row are separate SELECT queries combined with a UNION

Answer (score 0):

To get 1 if 1 line is 1 and 0 if both, you need to use MAX() function :

```
SELECT type, object_id,
 MAX(can_read),
 MAX(can_write),
 MAX(can_delete),
 MAX(can_create)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY type, object_id
```

Comment: How I do this over a union? Eg, the first row and second row are separate SELECT queries combined with a UNION.